# WCF concurrency & sendTimeout

Tags: wcf, concurrency, send

I meet a strange problem about WCF concurrency & sendTimeout.

This is my test programs:

WCF Service:
Uses net.Tcp binding, set InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple

It means service will uses multiple theads to process client's requests.

And the test result has improved it, I start 20 threads to invoke service's method via the same one communication channel.

The method of service is very simple:

```
public void GetData(int threadID)
```

Client will call this method with its threadID, service will output both thread ids of client & service itself.

This is the output of service:

At:3/6/2012 2:51:12 PM Start to process thread:7420, server thread id:3948

At:3/6/2012 2:51:42 PM Start to process thread:3600, server thread id:3948

At:3/6/2012 2:52:12 PM Start to process thread:6804, server thread id:3948

At:3/6/2012 2:52:14 PM Start to process thread:5840, server thread id:540

At:3/6/2012 2:52:15 PM Start to process thread:5688, server thread id:4000

At:3/6/2012 2:52:16 PM Start to process thread:6220, server thread id:5556

At:3/6/2012 2:52:17 PM Start to process thread:6332, server thread id:3380

At:3/6/2012 2:52:18 PM Start to process thread:7788, server thread id:548

At:3/6/2012 2:52:19 PM Start to process thread:7060, server thread id:6060

At:3/6/2012 2:52:20 PM Start to process thread:4724, server thread id:3836

At:3/6/2012 2:52:21 PM Start to process thread:6728, server thread id:420

At:3/6/2012 2:52:22 PM Start to process thread:7984, server thread id:6036

At:3/6/2012 2:52:23 PM Start to process thread:580, server thread id:3012

At:3/6/2012 2:52:24 PM Start to process thread:2412, server thread id:5472

At:3/6/2012 2:52:25 PM Start to process thread:2664, server thread id:172

At:3/6/2012 2:52:26 PM Start to process thread:6820, server thread id:5500

At:3/6/2012 2:52:27 PM Start to process thread:3340, server thread id:1056

At:3/6/2012 2:52:28 PM Start to process thread:6584, server thread id:3052

At:3/6/2012 2:52:29 PM Start to process thread:6156, server thread id:5784

At:3/6/2012 2:52:30 PM Start to process thread:6756, server thread id:724

But... strange thing happens when I set client side's sendTimeout from default 00:01:00 to 00:10:00, the result is like this:

At:3/6/2012 2:57:31 PM Start to process thread:3660, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 2:58:01 PM Start to process thread:6576, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 2:58:31 PM Start to process thread:7720, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 2:59:01 PM Start to process thread:8148, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 2:59:31 PM Start to process thread:7356, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 3:00:01 PM Start to process thread:8060, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 3:00:31 PM Start to process thread:6512, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 3:01:01 PM Start to process thread:8004, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 3:01:31 PM Start to process thread:7444, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 3:02:01 PM Start to process thread:5564, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 3:02:31 PM Start to process thread:7788, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 3:03:01 PM Start to process thread:6584, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 3:03:31 PM Start to process thread:5488, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 3:04:01 PM Start to process thread:356, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 3:04:32 PM Start to process thread:7912, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 3:05:02 PM Start to process thread:700, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 3:05:32 PM Start to process thread:7484, server thread id:5376

At:3/6/2012 3:06:02 PM Start to process thread:3960, server thread id:5376

It seems that servcie now only use one thread to process client's requests.
Is there any relationship between sendTimeout & concurrency? 
Or it is related to WCF's internal processing mechanism?